# UICollectionView Using Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, swift

In My Project I created Cell in UICollectionViewCell

Its got Error Terminating app due to uncaught exception

The code as follow.

**GalleryCell.swift**

```
class GalleryCell: UICollectionViewCell
{


@IBOutlet var titleLabel : UILabel


init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
}
```

and I used this cell in My ViewController:

The code as follow :

NextViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

 class NextViewController: UIViewController
 {

@IBOutlet var collectionView : UICollectionView



var ListArray=NSMutableArray()



override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()


    for i in 0..70
    {
         ListArray .addObject("C: \(i)")
    }




}



   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section:Int)->Int
    {
        return ListArray.count
   }


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)->UICollectionViewCell
{

  var  cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CELL", forIndexPath: indexPath) as GalleryCell


    cell.titleLabel.text="\(ListArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.item))"

    return cell
}


func collectionView(collectionView : UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
{

    return CGSizeMake(66, 58)
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

My issue is I am getting following error:

```
***** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier CELL - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'*** First throw call stack:**
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I added the following two lines in `NextViewController.swift` under `viewDidLoad()`:

```
var nibName = UINib(nibName: "GalleryCell", bundle:nil)

collectionView.registerNib(nibName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CELL")
```

The problem was that I was not registering the nib. Now that I'm doing that, it's working fine.

Answer (score 5):

the same for header/footer in swift:

```
    // register header accessory view:
    self.collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionReusableView.self,
        forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader,
        withReuseIdentifier: headerReuseIdentifier);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to register a cell class.

In your `viewDidLoad` write.

```
collectionView.registerClass(NSClassFromString("GalleryCell"),forCellWithReuseIdentifier:"CELL");
```

> Prior to calling the
>   *dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:* method of the
>   collection view, you must use this method or the
>   registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier: method to tell the collection
>   view how to create a new cell of the given type. If a cell of the
>   specified type is not currently in a reuse queue, the collection view
>   uses the provided information to create a new cell object
>   automatically.
>
> If you previously registered a class or nib file with the same reuse
>   identifier, the class you specify in the cellClass parameter replaces
>   the old entry. You may specify nil for cellClass if you want to
>   unregister the class from the specified reuse identifier.

Reference [registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/registerClass%3aforCellWithReuseIdentifier%3a)

Comment: Its getting following error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to register a cell class which is not a subclass of UICollectionViewCell ((null))'

Comment: @PREMKUMAR: Check your GalleryCell class. Did you made it as the subclass of UICollectionViewCell ? The issue is in the log itself

Comment: Thanks I am getting Answer. Thanks for spending your valuable time.

Comment: I had to state it this way:
self.collectionView.registerClass(CustomCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add another answer that helped me, in case it becomes useful to someone else.

It seems that everyone else has solved this problem through the use of `registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` or `registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:`.  For me, there was a different resolution: in my storyboard, I selected the header and looked over in the Identity Inspector in the top section where it has fields for my Custom Class.  Specifically, the **Module** field was blank.  I needed to pull down the arrow next to that field and select the right target.

Once I did this & saved the storyboard, the above crash no longer happened and I could see my custom header.