# Uicollectionview cell not loading binary data

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, binary-data

I am trying to load a core data binary image on a uicollectionview imageview cell. When I segue to the collection view controlller I am getting the error message "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" at theIssues.reloadData(). If I comment that out the screen is just black.

```
class theCollection: UICollectionViewCell {


var backButton = UIButton()
@IBOutlet var dx : UIImageView!


}

class collectionVIEW: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{

var users = [Item]()
@IBOutlet var theIssues: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    users = AppDelegate.cdHandler.fetchObject()


    theIssues.reloadData()
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return users.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! theCollection


    if let imageData = users[indexPath.row].image {

        let coredataLoadedimage = UIImage(data: imageData)
        cell.dx.image = coredataLoadedimage
        //
    }

    return cell
}
}
```

All I want to is get the binary data fetch and displayed on the collection view cell image view.

[image]

[image]

Comment: add exception breakPoint, check does your collectionView exists at the time, check if your cell dequeued correctly

Comment: I added a picture of what happens when I load the class hope that helps. @AlexandrKolesnik

Comment: Check your outlet, seems that is not correctly set

Comment: This is what somebody told me "Since you don’t set it in code anywhere, and it has the @IBOutlet attribute, it needs to be connected to a UICollectionView on your storyboard.". I don't know what that means. I connected the button via drag and drop. I don't know what else I can do.

Comment: @GustavoConde I added some more information in my comment above.

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik I added theIssues.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell") to view did load and the same issue keeps happening. When I segue to this view controller the error shows up however if I have the collection view load as the initial view controller it works.

Comment: @GustavoConde I added theIssues.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell") to view did load and the same issue keeps happening. When I segue to this view controller the error shows up however if I have the collection view load as the initial view controller it works.

Comment: @GustavoConde   this is a link to my project dropbox.com/s/peury7cgmbs24t8/NOTEBOOK.zip?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/peury7cgmbs24t8/NOTEBOOK.zip?dl=0 this is a link to my project hope you can look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must register theCollectionCell with collectionview before use it. If you don't register it due to crash app.

Comment: How do I do that? Do I put it in the view controller or collcectionviewcell class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177020/uicollectionview-using-swift

Comment: I added theIssues.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell") to view did load and the same issue keeps happening. When I segue to this view controller the error shows up however if I have the collection view load as the initial view controller it works.

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik this is a link to my project https://www.dropbox.com/s/peury7cgmbs24t8/NOTEBOOK.zip?dl=0

Comment: you moveRight func works wrong, you are creating new object and trying to present it, you must instantiate vc from storyboard replace with this @objc func moveRight() {
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "collection")
        self.present(vc, animated: true)
    }, don't forget to add identifier to your collectionViewController

Comment: when you say add identifier to your collectionViewController are you talking about storyboard id. Really appreciate your help so far. @AlexandrKolesnik